# Query to get list of customers whose orders are less than the previous order

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, data-warehouse

I am trying to write a sql to get the list of customers whose total ordered units is consistently lesser than the previous order. As in Total Qty in nth order is less than Total qty in n-1 th order, etc

**SQL to create and populate table**

```
create table orders (order_id int, customer_id varchar(5), order_date date, product_id varchar(5), quantity int);

Insert into orders values(01,'C1','2000-01-01','P1',10);
Insert into orders values(02,'C2','2002-01-01','P2',15);
Insert into orders values(03,'C3','2002-04-01','P3',17);
Insert into orders values(04,'C4','2003-04-01','P1',20);
Insert into orders values(05,'C4','2006-01-01','P2',1);
Insert into orders values(06,'C1','2006-05-01','P5',7);
```

I am assuming that I need to write a procedure and LOOP based on Order_id serial number. Once in loop, I need to pick the product_id and quantity Q corresponding to order_id. Then check whether for the same order_id there is any other quantity Q1 that is less than Q. If so, then I print the customer_id. 
If not, then the order_id moves to next order_id.

I am not sure how to implement the part where I check the quantity column to check whether there is any other quantity Q1 < Q for order_id?

Please clarify

Comment: how should the output look like?

Comment: OUTPUT will be the list of customers. 
C1
C4
Since both these customers have orders where the order is less than previous (7<10) for C1

Comment: Do you want to look at a customers' last and second last order only? Or are you generally looking for customers who had an order at some time that was lesser than some previous order? (The latter could be achieved with a simple `EXISTS` clause.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate row_numbers per each customer_id based on order_date. Then you have to join the nth row to the n-1th row for each customer and check to see if they have atleast one order where the quantity is less than the previous order.

[`SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c09154/15)

```
select t1.customer_id
from (select o.*,
      @rn:=if(@previous=customer_id,@rn,0) + 1 as rownum,
      @previous:=customer_id
      from orders o, (select @rn:=0,@previous:=NULL) t
      order by customer_id,order_date) t1
join (select o.*,
      @rn:=if(@previous=customer_id,@rn,0) + 1 as rownum,
      @previous:=customer_id
      from orders o
      order by customer_id,order_date) t2 
on t1.customer_id=t2.customer_id and t1.rownum=t2.rownum-1
group by t1.customer_id
having count(case when t2.quantity < t1.quantity then 1 end) >= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             (select o2.quantity
              from orders o2
              where o2.customer_id = o.customer_id and
                    o2.product_id = o.product_id and
                    o2.order_id < o.order_id
              order by o2.order_id desc
              limit 1
             ) prev_quantity
      from orders o
     ) o
where o.prev_quantity > o.quantity;
```

Comment: Does not work. I tried to update customerid as customer_id, and other updates to check if any records are provided, but still fails

Comment: @user1940212 . . . How does it "not work"?  That is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simple join on itself can do this for you, along with an embedded query to identify the correct row to join on based on the date.

```
SELECT o1.customer_id, o2.order_date, o1.quantity - o2.quantity AS quantity_less
FROM orders o1
INNER JOIN orders o2 ON o2.customer_id = o1.customer_id AND
                        o2.order_date = (SELECT MIN(order_date) FROM orders
                                         WHERE order_date > o1.order_date AND customer_id = o1.customer_id)
WHERE o2.quantity < o1.quantity
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Customer_ID
FROM
(
SELECT c.customer_id,c.order_date,c.quantity,p.quantity AS PreviousQuantity FROM orders c left join orders p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id AND c.order_date> p.order_date
WHERE c.quantity< p.quantity AND c.order_date>p.order_date
)A
EXCEPT
SELECT Customer_ID
FROM
(
SELECT c.customer_id,c.order_date,c.quantity,p.quantity AS PreviousQuantity FROM orders c left join orders p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id AND c.order_date> p.order_date
WHERE c.quantity> p.quantity  AND c.order_date>p.order_date
)B
```